# How to override a global method name to push my code in front before they call the original method

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I am trying to create an API on top of OpenGL and I want to not allow any calls to glActiveTexture without running through my overall texture handler first. Essentially someone needs to give an ID to the glActiveTexture method and I want to check that that slot isn't in use and if it is I want to redirect their request. I want to do this in a way that somehow allows me to inject code into that method before using the method so let the code look like this:

```
void glActiveTexture(int id){
    {opengl code}
}


//...some other file
int main(){
    glActiveTexture(2);
}
```

I want to do some macro trick or overloading tip to be able to make the code actually call MY version of glActiveTexture so that it can do something like this:

```
void glActiveTexture(int id){
    {my code}
    {opengl code}
}


//...some other file
int main(){
    glActiveTexture(2);
}
```

I am not too good at macros or the caveats of multiple same name methods but if there IS a 100% way of making it call my method over the opengl one, that would be great. If not, do you know of any ways to handle something like this. Essentially I need control over when the user would make calls to change the internal state of the program (the glActiveTexture call) and I want to do it in a way that lets opengl programmers still use the same syntax they normally would.

Comment: Well, if what you want is that calls to a function in a library executes first your code, I think that's not possible (without recompiling the library).

Comment: Which files you're able to modify? And also, which files you're able to recompile?

Comment: It depends on, but in common `glActiveTexture` is just a function pointer, so you can change it.

Comment: Load opengl function pointers locally where functions are implemented, expose your versions globally.

Comment: You can dynamicaly load opengl library and wrap it with your own implemantetion. But than you should implement all opengl methods even you dont want to customize.

Comment: On Linux and other Unix platforms you can use library preloading. Look up LD_PRELOAD.

Comment: It is not a way to do this (explained by other comments above). You should write a wrapper around openGL and ask other developers to use your wrapper instead of openGL functions directly. Otherwise it is hacking, not programming.

Comment: @pptaszni common bro hacking is a kind of programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is using preprocessor macros. You can use the following code, make sure to put it in an common include file that is included from everywhere in the code.

mygl.h:

```
// we will have to make sure that gl.h is inlcuded before our redefine
#include <gl/gl.h>

// we will check if it's not included from the implementation
#ifndef _DONTMANGLE
#define glActiveTexture myActiveTexture
#endif
```

Including `gl.h` before the macro makes sure you override the default GL behaviour. We use the `_DONTMANGLE` define to make sure that the function name doesn't get mangled by the preprocessor in the override implementation source file, so that we are still able to call the original function. 
Then define your function somewhere in the code:

mygl.c:

```
#define _DONTMANGLE
#include "mygl.h"

void myActiveTexture(GLint n)
{
    /// your code here
    return glActiveTexture(n);
}
```

Note that in some GL libraries (like MESA, or when using GLEE/GLEW helpers) `glActiveTexture` might already be a defined macro, so do not use `#undef` on it before redefining!

EDIT:

Something I forgot, is that you should not include the `#define` header file inside the source file where you host your `myActiveTexture` function. Otherwise, you will not be able to call `glActiveTexture`, as it will result in recursion! Another way is to use a define to exclude the mangling where applicable. I have updated the samples.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for. I am gonna do a little more research on making sure this works in all cases when I get to my work computer and when I finish my tests I will mark this as correct if it works.

Comment: Take a look into GLEE / GLEW headers to make sure it works with these, in case developers using your library plan to use these as well! I remember they had a weird way of defining functions.